# Cannot fetch record using AND (&&) using PHP and mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following query where I want to show particular records who fulfill criteria using where clause.

following is the query

```
select basic_information.*, service_history.*, inland_ic_information.* 
from service_history 
INNER JOIN basic_information 
ON service_history.pNo=basic_information.pNo 
INNER JOIN inland_ic_information 
ON service_history.pNo=inland_ic_information.pNo 
WHERE service_history.pNo = '4301587'  
and inland_ic_information.inlandcourseDescription ='A' 
and inland_ic_information.inlandcourseDescription ='B'
```

above query returns zero rows

when I use a single condition like

```
WHERE service_history.pNo = '4301587'  and inland_ic_information.inlandcourseDescription ='A'
```

or

```
  WHERE service_history.pNo = '4301587'  and inland_ic_information.inlandcourseDescription ='B'
```

it returns rows

but when I use both conditions same time it returns zero rows

Need your assistance

Comment: Can you post the schema and some example values? Seeing the comments/answers below.

Comment: how to post schema here  ?

Comment: [edit] the question and cut and paste.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to output all rows for a `pNo` value where that `pNo` is associated with rows that have `inlandcourseDescription` values of both `A` and `B`. You can do that with this query:

```
select basic_information.*, 
       service_history.*, 
       inland_ic_information.* 
from service_history 
INNER JOIN basic_information ON service_history.pNo=basic_information.pNo 
INNER JOIN inland_ic_information ON service_history.pNo=inland_ic_information.pNo 
WHERE service_history.pNo = '4301587'  
  AND (inland_ic_information.inlandcourseDescription = 'A'
   AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM inland_ic_information 
               WHERE pNo = '4301587' 
                 AND inlandcourseDescription = 'B')
    OR inland_ic_information.inlandcourseDescription = 'B'
   AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM inland_ic_information 
               WHERE pNo = '4301587' 
                 AND inlandcourseDescription = 'A')
       )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 

I need rows for which pNo='4301587' qualify both courses 'A' and 'B'

I need and condition not or


 IN('A', 'B')  returns rows whether he qualify course A or B ut i need to check for both courses

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand. You want rows which have `pNo = '4301587'` but *only if* rows with `inlandcourseDescription='A'` *and* `inlandcourseDescription='B'` exist?

Comment: yes exactly , i want rows with  pNo = '4301587'

and  inlandcourseDescription='A' and inlandcourseDescription='B'

Comment: But one row cannot have both those values, it can only be `A` or `B`, not both at the same time

Comment: on my database table, there are 2 rows for same pNo='4301587' who done both
inlandcourseDescription='A' and inlandcourseDescription='B'

Comment: @MuhammadTanzeelArshad see my edit. I think that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The where conditions of your 1st query make it 0 result.

```
and     inland_ic_information.inlandcourseDescription ='A' 
and     inland_ic_information.inlandcourseDescription ='B'
```

You can get result with OR like this:

```
WHERE   service_history.pNo = '4301587'  
AND     
        (
        inland_ic_information.inlandcourseDescription ='A' 
        OR  
        inland_ic_information.inlandcourseDescription ='B'
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 

I need rows for which pNo='4301587' qualify both courses 'A' and 'B'

I need and condition not or


 IN('A', 'B')  returns rows whether he qualify course A or B ut i need to check for both courses

Comment: Its return FALSE when there is no result. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-function.mysql-fetch-row.html

Comment: there is a result for both 'A' and 'B' so why it returns false?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do `LEFT JOIN` twice on the `inland_ic_information` table like this:

```
SELECT     *
FROM       service_history A
INNER JOIN basic_information B 
        ON A.pNo=B.pNo 
LEFT JOIN  inland_ic_information C 
       ON  A.pNo=C.pNo AND C.inlandcourseDescription ='A' 
LEFT JOIN  inland_ic_information D 
       ON  A.pNo=D.pNo AND D.inlandcourseDescription ='B' 
WHERE      A.pNo = '4301587'  
GROUP BY   A.pNo
HAVING     C.inlandcourseDescription IS NOT NULL 
AND        D.inlandcourseDescription IS NOT NULL
```